# What is the width in a CSS3 carousel doing?

Tags: css, carousel

I have the following fiddle of a working CSS3 carousel.

Can somebody tell me why the

```
width: 25%;
```

in the CSS on the last line of CSS, does what it does?

Here is the working fiddle of the CSS carousel.

http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/k6zZG/

Comment: If you bring it down to about 10% you'll see why. The author has placed the images after one another inside a div and using radio buttons for controlling the "slide effect". So when the images are at 25% they fill up the whole div and when clicking a radio button the other 25% fills up the div. Pretty clever, if you ask me.

Comment: @simpe be bold, post it as an answer.

Comment: yeah @simpe , the author , i noticed has made good use of math , as thanks for ur 10% trick , i'll do that and see what Happens .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole "slide effect" is based on radio buttons triggering the CSS3 effect. The author has placed 4 images after one another, each of 25% width, making it together 100% width. When clicking a radio button the transition effect is triggered and another 25% of the div containing all images are shown.

**Radio buttons**

```
<input checked type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide1"/>
<label for="Slide1" id="s1"></label>
...
```

**When clicking a radio button**

```
#Slide2:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper{ margin-left: -100%; }
```

**CSS3 transition effect**

```
.overflow-wrapper{
    width: 400%;
    ...
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

I hope this answered your question.

If not - check out my updated version of the jsFiddle (changed the width to 10%): http://jsfiddle.net/k6zZG/4/ and you'll probably figure it out on your own!

Comment: actually in the css on line 72 and line 8 if you comment out the CSS Overflow property , its even more evident of how the carousel works . heres a JS fiddle i created , http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/P8ZZ7/ .